# Magento: Getting list of products programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to get a list of products from my Magento store, and I only need three attributes loaded per product, which, I figure, would take a lot less time than if I were to load the whole product. Now, either I'm not doing it right, or, I'm wrong assuming above. Here's my script:

```
<?php
$script_start = microtime(true);

// Load Magento core
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// Load products :: collection

$query_create_start = microtime(true);

$prod_catalog = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->
            addAttributeToSelect('sku')->
            addAttributeToSelect('name')->
            addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');

$query_create_end = microtime(true);

$query_create_time = $query_create_end - $query_create_start;

echo "Query creation took $query_create_time seconds.<br>";

$product_loop_start = microtime(true);
foreach($prod_catalog as $product) {
    var_dump($product);
    $one_product_loop = microtime(true);
    $one_product_time =  $one_product_loop - $product_loop_start;
    echo "Getting one product took $one_product_time seconds.<";
    die('done');
}
$product_loop_end = microtime(true);

?>
```

And here's output(without dump data):

```
Query creation took 0.0043220520019531 seconds.
one product took 32.509027004242 seconds
```

Now, when I take a look at the product var_dump, I see that it loaded more attributes than I asked:

```
object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)#74 (32) {
  ["_cacheTag":protected]=>
  string(15) "catalog_product"
  ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
  string(15) "catalog_product"
  ["_eventObject":protected]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["_canAffectOptions":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_typeInstance":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_typeInstanceSingleton":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_linkInstance":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_customOptions":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_urlModel":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_errors":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_optionInstance":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_options":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_reservedAttributes":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_isDuplicable":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_calculatePrice":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_defaultValues":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_storeValuesFlags":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_lockedAttributes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_isDeleteable":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_isReadonly":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_resourceName":protected]=>
  string(15) "catalog/product"
  ["_resource":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=>
  string(26) "catalog/product_collection"
  ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(12) {
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["entity_type_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["attribute_set_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["type_id"]=>
    string(6) "simple"
    ["sku"]=>
    string(10) "1000000000"
    ["has_options"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["required_options"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2016-07-11 11:05:03"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-03-03 21:14:21"
    ["name"]=>
    string(62) "My simple product"
    ["is_salable"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["stock_item"]=>
    object(Varien_Object)#49 (7) {
      ["_data":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["is_in_stock"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
      ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_origData":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_origData":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
  string(9) "entity_id"
  ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When system load one product, it will load all static attributes by default.

Static attribute is stored in main entity table "catalog_product_entity", other attributes are stored in related table according the backen_type of this attribute. For example, 'name" is stored in 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'.

**addAttributeToSelect** method only impact non-static attributes, So in your case you can see so many static attributes that have been load.

You can try below code:

```
$prod_catalog = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();          
$prod_catalog->getSelect()->reset("columns")->columns(array("sku","entity_id"));
$prod_catalog->addAttributeToSelect('name');
foreach($prod_catalog as $product) {
 $category_ids =  $product->getCategroyIds();
 ###you code
}
```

Tips:though category_ids is static, but there is no column in main entity table as well as other product entity table, so it make no sense to run addAttributeToSelect('categroy_ids') or add to columns function, category ids data is from another table catalog_category_product")

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Mage::getResourceModel(‘catalog/product’)->getAttributeRawValue($productId, $atrributeCode, $storeId)` for single attribute instead of `getCollection()`, may be quicker for you needs.

Answer (score 0):

you have the flat products enabled.
The flat tables generated by the flat product indexer contain only active products.
This is for performance reasons. There is no need to index the disabled products since you are not going to use them on front end. (and the flat tables are used only on front-end).

If you are trying to get your products in a custom script and you need to get the disabled ones then you can do this.

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->...add filters here.

Comment: No I'm not using flat tables. If I were, it would throw an error, as addAttributeToSelect() doesn't work on flat.